# Would vs Will usage in present tense

Tags: would, will-would

Can would be used like this - 
If you talk to him , you would find out how stupid he is . 
This could have been - " If you talked to him , you would find out how stupid he is " 
Second one is an example of second conditional and it's very less likely to happen . How's this sentence different from the previous one

Comment: The first one should be, "If you talk to him, you will find out how stupid he is."

Comment: Isabel's version supposes that 'talking to him' will take place in the future. _If you talked to him_ or _if you were to talk to him_ make the conversation hypothetical.